# find similarity of merchant with customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in sql server 2012 that have this columns:
user_id , merchant_id

I want to find top 5  similar partners for each merchant. 
The similarity is simply defined by normalized number of overlapping costumers;

i can not find any solution for this problem.

Comment: Please edit your question, providing sample data and desired results.  What does "normalized number of overlapping customers" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query counts the number of common customers for two merchants:

```
select t.merchantid as m1, t2.merchantid as m2, count(*) as common_customers
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.customerid = t2.customerid and t.merchantid <> t2.merchantid
group by t.merchantid, t2.merchantid;
```

The following gets the five based on the raw couns:

```
select *
from (select t.merchantid as m1, t2.merchantid as m2, count(*) as common_customers,
             row_number() over (partition by t.merchantid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table t join
           table t2
           on t.customerid = t2.customerid and t.merchantid <> t2.merchantid
      group by t.merchantid, t2.merchantid
     ) mm
where seqnum <= 5;
```

I do not know what you mean by "normalized".  The term "normalized" in statistics would often not change the ordering of values (but would result in the sum of the squares being 1), so this may do what you want.

Comment: `t` and `t2` are table aliases -- needed for a self join.  `table` means that your tablename goes there.

Comment: i have to duplicate tables ?!

Comment: i use this query and run correctly but have some problem :

Comment: select *
from (select t.merchant_id as m1, t2.merchant_id as m2, count(*) as common_customers,
             row_number() over (partition by t.merchant_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from train_format1 as t  join
            train_format1 as t2
           on t.user_id = t2.user_id and t.merchant_id <> t2.merchant_id
      group by t.merchant_id, t2.merchant_id 
     ) mm

Comment: i want only top 5 seqnum